# .ContinueWith() and object state

Tags: c#, lambda, async-await, task, idisposable

I'm waffling between which is better (in terms of aesthetics, idiomatic-ness, and performance):

```
public async Task<string> DecryptAsync(string encrypted)
{
    SymmetricAlgorithm aes = this.GetAes();

    return await this.DecryptAsync(aes, encrypted).ContinueWith(
        (decryptTask, objectState) =>
        {
            (objectState as IDisposable)?.Dispose();
            return decryptTask.Result;
        },
        aes);
}
```

or

```
public async Task<string> DecryptAsync(string encrypted)
{
    SymmetricAlgorithm aes = this.GetAes();

    return await this.DecryptAsync(aes, encrypted).ContinueWith(decryptTask =>
    {
        aes.Dispose();
        return decryptTask.Result;
    });
}
```

The main difference being that the second one captures the `aes` variable in the lambda while the first one passes it as a parameter then casts it to the appropriate type.

A third consideration, inspired by [Oxald](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9445781/oxald) and [Servy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1159478/servy):

```
public async Task<string> DecryptAsync(string encrypted)
{
    using (SymmetricAlgorithm aes = this.GetAes())
    {
        return await this.DecryptAsync(aes, encrypted);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've always figured that if casting can be avoided, then avoid it.

Comment: I wonder if "using(SymmetricAlgorithm aes = this.GetAes())" is a better working solution, since "using" statement already works fine along with IEnumerable/yield pattern.

Comment: Why did you tag the question with [tag:async-await] if you aren't actually using `await`?  And more importantly, why aren't you using `await`?

Comment: @Oxald yours is an excellent question - I came to this design because of `HttpClient`'s `HttpResponseMessage` `Content.ReadAsStreamAsync` would be invalid if the `HttpResponseMessage` was wrapped in a `using` as it would `Dispose()` before reading from the steam, making it invalid. The `ContinueWith()` pattern became part of the solution there.

Comment: @Servy sorry, I elided it at that level due to a ReSharper hint. Put them back in for now.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer There unnecessary when you use `ContinueWIth` (incorrectly) to try to run code after the task finishes. They're not unnecessary when you use `await` to run code after a task finishes, with the proper semantics.

Comment: @Servy allow me to add a third alternative then for consideration.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer : did you test your third approach? does it have the same side effects described in your previous comment (with HttpClient) ?

Comment: Now just declare the string before the using block, assign it inside the using block and return it after the using block and you're set.

Comment: @JessedeWit do you have an authoritative source for that?

Comment: @Oxald working up a full test now. I hope this is the solution as it's the cleanest looking of the bunch.

Comment: @Oxald seems to be totally workable at this point.

Comment: @JesseSlicer, it is not necessary to declare the string outside the using block, but it does avoid confusion about when the object is disposed. No performance cost + more readable = better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using await instead of ContinueWith. the result of await equals Task.Result. The Disposing of aes can be done using a using statement:

```
public async Task<string> DecryptAsync(string encrypted)
{
    using (SymmetricAlgorithm aes = this.GetAes())
    {
        string decryptedText = await this.DecryptAsync(aes, encrypted);
        return decryptedText;
    };
}
```